# How to implement a collapsing header in Android with Motion Layout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I am new to Motion Layout and want to implement a collapsing header when the user swipes up the recyclerview.

The header animation is kind of working, however in the main activity layout, the header is just getting smaller and clipped, but not collapsing with the animation.

Any hints as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Here are both layouts and respective scene files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerLayout"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_row" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/header_scene"
    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/product_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/product"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="230dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

activity_main_scene.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/headerLayout"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerLayout" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:motionProgress="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerLayout" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

header_scene.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">>
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/imageView"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
            motion:pathMotionArc="startHorizontal" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            motion:layout_constraintGuide_begin="230dp" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            motion:layout_constraintGuide_begin="80dp" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```